# How to replace outlier values with mean in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, outliers

I want to know how to replace outlier values with mean. I have dataframe I could able to find the outlier and filter the rows and now I want to replace it with mean values. How do I do it?

df is like:

```
       a     b
1      27    0
2      10    1
3      80    2
4      21    3
5      46    4
6      100   5
```

After finding IQR I get outliers as this:

```
Upper = 75
lower = 12
outliers = df.filter((df['a'] > upper) | (df['a'] < lower))
2      10    1
3      80    2
6      100   5
```

Now I found the mean:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean as _mean, col
mean= df.select(_mean(col('a')).alias('mean')).collect()
mean = mean[0]['mean']
mean : 31.333
```

Now I am not understanding how do I replace the mean by rounding it to 31 and replace it with the outlier values in pyspark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when` to replace the outlier values using the given conditions. To replace with the mean, you can use the `mean` window function instead of collecting it to a variable, and round it to the nearest integer using `F.round`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

upper = 75
lower = 12

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'a', 
    F.when(
        (df['a'] > upper) | (df['a'] < lower), 
        F.round(F.mean('a').over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1)))).cast('int')
        # or you can use 
        # F.round(F.lit(df.select(F.mean(F.col('a')).alias('mean')).collect()[0]['mean'])).cast('int')
    ).otherwise(F.col('a'))
)

df2.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
| 27|  0|
| 47|  1|
| 47|  2|
| 21|  3|
| 46|  4|
| 47|  5|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please share any link about this? I want to understand what is F.lit() is doing

Comment: @toi you can see the relevant [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit)

Comment: `orderBy(lit(1))` is just a dummy ordering column for the window. A window has to be provided to the `mean` spark sql function, but you want to get the mean over the whole dataframe, so you can use a dummy window.

Comment: for the second `lit` function in the commented code, it's converting the mean value you collected into a column, which is then rounded and cast to an integer